# I am trying to connect my Django app with Mysql database but when I tried to migrate loads of error started to pop up in the terminal.

Tags: python, mysql, django

I tried various ways (every solution mentioned in the stackoverflow) to solve the problem but still the problems continues.

When I run : "python manage.py migrate" the following error is shown

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 61, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 9, in check_database_backends
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 226, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Manish/Projects/Websites/SanirTVNetwork/SanirTV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Then I tried: "pip install mysql-python" as per the suggestions in the stackoverflow similar questions. I got the following error

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/7_/cx21vvvn5cqdypfndc7j_jl80000gn/T/pip-build-JjMQeR/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/7_/cx21vvvn5cqdypfndc7j_jl80000gn/T/pip-build-JjMQeR/mysql-python/
```

I even tried: "brew install mysql-connector-c" but the same error starts to come.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using macOS Sierra

Comment: Did you actually mean to use python2? Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I am using a virtualenv. I am using python 2.7

Comment: Try installing it system wide, does that work?

Comment: I tried installing it to the whole system but the same error is displayed everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it:
First I installed the command line developer tools required by running the following code inside the virtualenv

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

Then I installed MySQL-python by using the following code

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Finally I migrated the database using:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

It worked without any errors
The main problem with the error was that I didn't installed the command line developer tools required.